# how to add div content to empty jsp body dynamically

Tags: jquery, jsp

> how to load html content into a separate empty JSP page.when i call the jsp page in url the loaded content need to display .

Comment: did you try  <%@include  file="some.html" %> ?

Comment: my things is like i have many widgets . when i select any widget it generate selected html content . That html content , i need to load to empty jsp page body .